# использовать combobox в dialog

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jdialog

Создаю переменные в начале класса:

```
int currentItem;
    String[] idNumbers;
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Далее поскольку `id` генерируется само собой, использую метод, который обновляет ID, когда данные работника удаляют или же создают "нового работника".

```
public void updateIDNumbers() {

        idNumbers = new String[list.size()];
        int i = 0;

        for (Employee e : list) {
            idNumbers[i++] = e.getId() + "";
        }

        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(idNumbers));
    }
```

Также есть простой метод, который отображает обновленные данные.

```
public void displayDetails(int currentItem) {

        idTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getId() + "");
        ppsTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getPps());
        nameTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getName());
        surnameTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getSurname());
        genderTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getGender() + "");
        depTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getDep());
        salaryTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getSalary() + "");
        fulltimeTextField.setText(list.get(currentItem).getFulltime() + "");

    }
```

А теперь вызываю метод, который должен открыть диалог и позвонить выбрать `id`, а далее отобразить на страничке работника с выбранным `id`.

```
byIdItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (modifyItemButton.getText().equals("Save") ) {
            // Here we make sure that any updated values are saved to the record before
            // we display the next record.
            // This behaviour is performed by next, prev and edit, so we move it into a
            // separate method so as to avoid unnecessary repetition of code.
            saveOpenValues();                   
        }

    updateIDNumbers();

     String[] options = { "OK", "Cancel"};

     String title = "Search an ID";

    int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, combo, title,
           JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
           options, options[0]);

     if (selection > 0) {
        System.out.println("selection is: " + options[selection]);
     }

     //  currentItem = ((JComboBox)(e.getSource())).getSelectedIndex();
     currentItem = (Integer) combo.getSelectedItem();


     if (currentItem != 0) {
        displayDetails(currentItem);
        System.out.println("hey");

     }
            }

        });
```

Ошибка вполне понятна  -  `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` Однако никак не могу понять как переконвертировать `string` в `integer`, перепробовала разные варианты...
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы передали в комбо-бокс массив **строк**:

```
String[] idNumbers;
...    
combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(idNumbers));
```

Метод `getSelectedItem()` возвращает выбранный элемент, который является строкой (какой-то строкой из переданного массива). Как вы хотите получить из него число?
Если вам нужен номер выбранного элемента, используйте `combo.getSelectedIndex();`
если в массиве строк у вас строковые представления чисел (типа "123"), то используйте `Integer.parseInt(combo.getSelectedItem())`